# Why is my character passing through the object even though I have configured box colliders and rigidbody for them?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Check inspection for: [Blocking wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRpGO.png)

Check inspection for: [character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPvtM.png)

It still passes through the blocking wall.

In Script in character:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 15 * Time.deltaTime);
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
{
    transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * 15 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Is the collider weel defined? maybe the collision part is lower than expected

Comment: Try removing the rigidbody from the blocking wall. [This page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) might help, check out the section on static colliders.

Answer (score 1):

Use the rigidbody.AddForce function to move your player/object.
Translating the transform is more like teleporting than moving. So your object teleports to the other side of the wall with transform.Translate.
Check this link for the rigidbody.AddForce movement method: [Unity - Moving the player](https://unity3d.com/de/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player)

**Update 1**
You should also set the collision detection to continuous instead of discrete.

Answer (score 1):

*You components are correctly set:* one rigidbody at the character and colliders in both the character and the wall.

*As said by Greg:* if you want to move your character in a more realistic way(based in the unity physics) you may want to change your code to use AddForce instead. However, its not mandatory. If you're doing something like a space invaders game, move the character the way you are doing is ok.

Another thing you **should** consider is the possibility of the wall collider be too thin. If that is the case, unity could not be able to detect the collision properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your object is moving quickly you might want to change [Collision Detection: Descrete to a Continuous](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CollisionDetectionMode.html) one in the inspector. Also, you might want to modify the rigidbody velocity for movement instead.

Also. Make sure you're not using 3d objects and 2d objects combined. They don't match. A 2D object wont collide with a 3D object.

```
RigidBody rb;

void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
}


void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
         rb.velocity = Vector3.forward * 15 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        rb.velocity = -Vector3.forward * 15 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: Might need to adjust the values a bit!

Comment: What if I don't want to move it to forward of the body but only to forward in z axis? How do I change this then?

Comment: Change the Vector3.forward to something that represents the your desired direction. (Forward should be z axis) You could write it all out with "new Vector3(0, 0, 1)" and 0, 0, -1 or use one of the shorthands: forward, back, up, down. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You do need Rigid body component on your wall at all. Collider itself will cause the collision.

For Unity physics to work properly you should not modify transform position directly but move your character by using forces.

Try this:

```
void FixedUpdate() {

Rigidbody rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
       rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * 15f);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
       rb.AddForce(-Vector3.forward * 15f);
    }

}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to move it to forward of the body but only to forward in z axis? How do I change this then?